# Variables not being defined when i try to open a file

Tags: python

I am writing a simple login program in python and I tried assigning the `open("file_name", "mode")` to a variable but I got these errors that say that the variables were not defined.

```
openfle = open("login_info.txt", "r")
readfle = openfle.read(1)
print(readfle)
```

Comment: can you also add the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a possible error in your code. But, usually when working with files, using the `with` keyword is usually recommended. For example:

```py
with open("login_info.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read(1)
print(content)
```

Comment: you might also want to add the reason why it is recommended as the file gets closed automatically when the context manager scope ends after the `with` block is exited.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
readfile = open("login_info.txt").read()
print(readfile)
```

If you have a variable and it has a function on it, you can use the function directly. Also, at `open()` the `"r"` is standard, so you don't need to define it.

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.